# How to remove some XML Tag and all tags / data in it using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, xml, svg

i want to remove `foreignobject` tags and all the tags inside it and text inside this tag using Java Regex.

Following is the XML :

```
    <svg class="noselect orgchartsvg"><defs><filter id="default" x="0" y="0" width="110%" height="110%"><feoffset result="offout" in="sourcegraphic" dx="1" dy="1" /><fecolormatrix result="matrixout" in="offout" type="matrix" values="0.8  0   0  0  0 0   0.8  0  0  0 0    0  0.8 0  0 0    0  0   1  0 " /><fegaussianblur result="blurout" in="matrixout" stddeviation="2" /><feblend in="sourcegraphic" in2="blurout" mode="normal" /></filter><filter id="hover" x="0" y="0" width="110%" height="110%"><feoffset result="offout" in="sourcegraphic" dx="1" dy="1" /><fecolormatrix result="matrixout" in="offout" type="matrix" values="0.3686  0   0  0  0 0   0.5529  0  0  0 0    0  0.9804 0  0 0    0  0   1  0 " /><fegaussianblur result="blurout" in="matrixout" stddeviation="2" /><feblend in="sourcegraphic" in2="blurout" mode="normal" /></filter><filter id="selected" x="0" y="0" width="110%" height="110%"><feoffset result="offout" in="sourcegraphic" dx="3" dy="3" /><fecolormatrix result="matrixout" in="offout" type="matrix" values="0.3686  0   0  0  0 0  0.5529  0  0  0 0    0  0.9804 0  0 0    0  0   1  0 " /><fegaussianblur result="blurout" in="matrixout" stddeviation="2" /><feblend in="sourcegraphic" in2="blurout" mode="normal" /></filter></defs><g class="transgroup" transform="scale(1)" ><line y1="157" x1="0" y2="157" x2="-17" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="99" x1="-17" y2="99" x2="672" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="99" x1="672" y2="41" x2="672" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="273" x1="0" y2="273" x2="-17" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="389" x1="0" y2="389" x2="-17" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="505" x1="0" y2="505" x2="-17" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="621" x1="0" y2="621" x2="-17" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="621" x1="-17" y2="99" x2="-17" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="157" x1="345" y2="157" x2="328" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="273" x1="345" y2="273" x2="328" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="389" x1="345" y2="389" x2="328" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="505" x1="345" y2="505" x2="328" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="621" x1="345" y2="621" x2="328" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="621" x1="328" y2="99" x2="328" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="157" x1="690" y2="157" x2="673" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="273" x1="690" y2="273" x2="673" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="389" x1="690" y2="389" x2="673" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="505" x1="690" y2="505" x2="673" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="621" x1="690" y2="621" x2="673" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="621" x1="673" y2="99" x2="673" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="157" x1="1035" y2="157" x2="1018" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="99" x1="1018" y2="99" x2="672" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="273" x1="1035" y2="273" x2="1018" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="389" x1="1035" y2="389" x2="1018" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><line y1="389" x1="1018" y2="99" x2="1018" style="fill:#292a2b;stroke:#292a2b;stroke-width:1;" /><g uid="1" data-is-root="true" data-id="49090049" data-type="position" class="nodegroup select" dotted="false"><rect filter="url(#default)" expand-type="null" tabindex="-1" x="517" width="18" y="0" data-id="49090049" pptrect="1" data-type="position" class="leftborderposition leftborder" height="82"></rect><rect filter="url(#default)" expand-type="null" tabindex="207" x="535" width="292" y="0" data-id="49090049" pptrect="1" data-type="position" class="rect select" height="82"></rect><switch class="select">

<foreignobject x="545" width="282" y="10" data-id="49090049" style="text-align:left;" data-type="position" class="foreignobject null select" height="62"><body><div class="node clearfix">
  <div class="node-portrait">
            <img src="services/userservice/image?uid=72299&plantype=&planname=" style="border-radius: 50%;" class="select circularimage" height="60"></img>
</div>

  <div class="node-content">
    <div class="node-content-item node-content-bold" title="director, manufacturing">director, manufacturing</div>
<div class="node-content-item node-content-normal" title="helle carlson">helle carlson</div>
    <div class="node-content-icons clearfix">      

      <div class="node-content-item node-content-normal" title="chicago">chicago</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body></foreignobject></svg>
```

I have tried this one 
`(<foreignobject[^>]*[^/]>)[^&]*(?!\\s*</foreignobject>)` but it doenst remove.

`mysvg = mysvg.replaceAll("(<foreignobject[^>]*[^/]>)[^&]*(?!\\s*</foreignobject>)"," ");`

Comment: Regex is not recommended.  A better idea would be to parse the XML into a DOM tree and manipulate it that way.

Comment: Here is the canonical answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/630136. The short version is: don't.

Comment: Yes i know but is there a way in regex to do that?

Comment: Yes, but it will break and will malfunction in ways you did not foresee. It'll fail for empty `<foreignobject/>` tags, if there's mixed namespaces, if namespace prefixes are unexpected, if there's HTML entity references in attributes in the tag, if there's nested foreignobjects... Meanwhile this is absolutely trivial to solve in XSLT which was made specifically for handling XML, so use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done using XML Parsing at the end